# What's the meaning of if(a,b,c,d) in C Language

Tags: c, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Comma Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator)

I had been looked if statement in C Language. like this.

```
if (a, b, c, d) {

    blablabla..
    blablabla..

}
```

What's the meaning of this if statement ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have there is an example of the comma operator. It evaluates all four expressions but uses `d` for the `if` statement.

Unless the expressions other than `d` have side effects (like `a++` for example) they're useless. You can see it in operation with the mini-program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    if (1,0) printf ("1,0\n");
    if (0,1) printf ("0,1\n");
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
0,1
```

Most people use this without even realising it, as in:

```
for (i = 0, j = 100; i < 10; i++, j--) ...
```

The `i = 0`, `j = 100`, `i++` and `j++` are components of two full expressions each of which uses the comma operator.

The relevant part of the standard is `C11 6.5.17 Comma operator`:

> **Syntax:**
>
> `expression:`
>      `assignment-expression`
>      `expression , assignment-expression`
>
> **Semantics:**
>
> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.
>
> EXAMPLE:
>
> As indicated by the syntax, the comma operator (as described in this subclause) cannot appear in contexts where a comma is used to separate items in a list (such as arguments to functions or lists of initializers). On the other hand, it can be used within a parenthesized expression or within the second expression of a conditional operator in such contexts. In the function call:
>
> `f(a, (t=3, t+2), c)`
>
> the function has three arguments, the second of which has the value 5.

Answer (score 4):

the comma operator:
evaluate a and b and c and d in sequence and return the result of d.

Answer (score 2):

It evaluates a, then b, then c, then d, and uses the value of `d` as the condition for the `if`. The other three are evaluated, but normally only for side-effects -- the results are discarded.